# Is it possible to detect what was input in console?

Tags: javascript

I have been fiddling around with different events in js and was thinking if there is a way to track the input in the console i.e. inspect element in chrome?

I looked online for some ideas but I could not find anything similar to what I am asking. The code I tried only works for the current window I am on excluding the console window.

```
window.onkeydown = function (e) {
        console.log(e.key);
    };
```

This will track the users key presses within the window. I tried using document and add event listener but no luck. Is there a way to edit this to track console key presses in the current page? If that is not possible is it possible to get a log of what was used in it? I'm trying to get all my console.log commands to help with debugging.

Comment: Don't think so. **[Here's the spec.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console)** on the `console` API.

Comment: you can replace `console.log()` with one that logs and pipes.

Comment: ill give that a read, thanks